# Jquery form in the same page

Tags: jquery, forms

My question is about forms with jQuery, usually the pages uses forms with jQuery need call other page for send the form or verificate the same without reload the page.

My question: is it possible to use jQuery with forms in the same page and no need call other for works fine?

For example if I have this simple form in php and html:

**PHP CODE**

```
<div id="request">
    <?php 
        if ($_REQUEST[ 'send']=="ok" ) { 
            if ($_REQUEST[ 'username']=="" ) { 
                print "bad field"; 
            } else { 
                print "Form send ok"; 
            } 
        } 
    ?>
</div>
```

**HTML CODE**

```
<form id="forma" name="form" method="post" action="?">
    <input type="text" name="username" id="textfield" />
    <input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Send Message" />
    <input type="hidden" name="send" id="ok">
</form>
```

How I can send this form from this same page and no call other or external page with jQuery, it´s possible process all inside the same page and use jquery for no reload ?

I don´t know many about jQuery with forms by this if it´s possible put code for after this create more things

Thanks for the help

Comment: why use jquery? you could just add a <input type="submit" value="submit"/> to your form

Comment: I don´t want reload the page man it´s for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes there you can use ajax (asynchronous javascript) to do that like

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "some.php",
  data: { name: "John", location: "Boston" }
}).done(function( msg ) {
  alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
});
```

see [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) to use as you like.

Comment: In the same page? but how i load only the div for the form because in that page i have the header , footer etc and if i call the same page load all other time

Comment: using ajax you can load a particular division .Give some time see the documentation and you can learn it by 1 hr max no one here can give you code because you have to use it as per your needs :)

Comment: Ah okok , for example some as thi s: jQuery('#home').load(link+' #home_content');

Comment: Ok if you want to load a contnt from a page to a div without having the page reloaded then in my example in the `url:` part give the url name and in the `success` like $('youurdiv').html(msg);

Answer (score 0):

You try with this code.

in js file.

```
var username = $('input[name="username"]').val();
var send = $('input[name="send"]').val();
$.post("somePHP.php", {name : username, send: send}, function(response){
// your code..
})
```

in somePHP.php

```
<?php 
        if(isset($_POST['send']) && isset($_POST['username']){
           if ($_POST['send']=="ok" ) { 
            if ($_POST[ 'username']=="" ) { 
                print "bad field"; 
            } else { 
                print "Form send ok"; 
            } 
           } 
        }

    ?>
```